# How to compare a client side time with a server side file modification time?

Tags: php, angularjs, http

I have a client(client1) that keeps doing http polling to a .txt that is on a php server and a have another client(client2) that keeps modifying that .txt on the server. 
I want to know when (client2) stops modifying the .txt.
I came with the solution to compare client time and the last time the .txt was modified. so the (client1) get aware that (client2) is not connected.
But I do not how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use another approach.
Read about socket.io

> wikipedia defition
>
> Socket.IO is a JavaScript library for realtime web applications. It enables realtime, bi-directional communication between web clients and servers. ... Socket.IO provides the ability to implement real-time analytics, binary streaming, instant messaging, and document collaboration.

So when a data is modified in the server side your internet browser is "notified"

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/?redirect_from_locale=fr

https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

Comment: Ok. I read a little about socket.io, that is works with php ?.

Comment: This librairy make websocket in php : http://hoa-project.net/En/Literature/Hack/Websocket.html